# Trying to create a simple gallery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, image-gallery

I am trying to 'shunt' the position of a collection of images in a slider to the left/right whenever a user clicks the corresponding button in the slider. I have this working but the code is a little big and repetitive so I've been trying to clear it up a little bit, this is it in it's current state:

```
$('#btnRight').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (parseInt(6 + indexx) != 10) {
        indexx++;
        $('#first').attr('src', $('#second').attr('src'));
        $('#second').attr('src', $('#third').attr('src'));
        $('#third').attr('src', $('#fourth').attr('src'));
        $('#fourth').attr('src', $('#fifth').attr('src'));
        $('#fifth').attr('src', $('#sixth').attr('src'));
        $('#sixth').attr('src', '/Content/Images/Gallery/Thumbs/' + parseInt(6 + indexx) + '.png');
    }
});
```

You can see that it's manually selecting each element and swapping the source attribute to move the images to the right.

Here is the code that I've been working on improving but doesn't quite work:

```
$('#btnLeft').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#gallerySlider img").each(function (index) {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).prev().attr("src"));
    });
});
```

This takes the first image in the current collection and just sets the source of all of the images in `#gallerySlider` which is wrong. But if I put the same code inside an alert it correctly shows the image and it's previous one e.g. the output is similar to:

`/Content/Images/Design/Thumbs/10.png Previous Image: /Content/Images/Design/Thumbs/9.png`

So it's selecting the images correctly and giving me back the right `src` but why does it set the source of all of the images in the slider to the same one? Surely it should go through all of them and:

`$(this).prev().attr("src")`

Will be different for each one?

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong here?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer by user1166905 sounds quite alright. A solution would be that if you want to move to the left you take the first element out of the div and place it back into the div at the end.
The same is true if you press right. You take the last element from your list, remove it from the div and place it at the beginning of your gallery div again.

```
$('#btnLeft').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#gallerySlider').append($("#gallerySlider img").first());
}); 

$('#btnRight').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#gallerySlider').prepend($("#gallerySlider img").last());
});
```

I think that should do the trick

Comment: I'll give this a try, seems to make sense. Another idea i thought of was storing all of the images in an array and then using the index in the `each` to set the source correctly?

Comment: your array solution will work but when you use it you'll have to maintain your list of images in two locations, which I usually don't do because it can cause problems in the future ;)

Comment: Works fine thanks! Don't have to bother with bounds checking either as it just loops through, good stuff.

Comment: How would this work for pressing the right button? `$("#gallerySlider").append($("#gallerySlider img:last").first());`?

Comment: well now i see that i did some double stuff first off for the left you can eighter use $("#gallerySlider img:first") or $("#gallerySlider img").first(); for the righ button you should do something like $("#gallerySlider img:last") or $("#gallerySlider img").last() and instead of appending you do prepending to add the at the front of all images

Answer (score 1):

If you imagine image 1 is "img1.jpg" and image 2 is "img2.jpg" etc.

The code you have put would set image 2 to "img1.jpg", then next it would set image 3 to image 2's src which would now be "img1.jpg" and this image would become the src for all of them in the end.  Does that make sense?

Have you looked online for jQuery type gallery plugins as there are loads out there which will do the job for you?

Comment: Yeah i see what you mean now. Ooops. I'd rather not use a plugin, I'm new to jQuery so would like to learn as much as I can rather than just grab a plugin everytime I have a problem.